# How do I capture still photographs in a RealityKit app?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I have an augmented reality app built using RealityKit in Swift 5. I would like to capture a RAW image of the underlying scene (without virtual objects). I am running the code below, however it never captures any photos but gives me an error message that says "Cannot Record". The documentation is somewhat scant on this, so any help would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation



class CapturePhoto: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    


    
    var capture = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    var availableCameraSettings: Array<AVCapturePhotoSettings> = []
    var session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    let prompt = Prompt()

    override init(){
        
        super.init()
 
        createSettings()
        configOutput()
        configSession()
        startSesssion()
 
        // do any other config here
        
    }
    
    func configOutput(){
        capture.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
        capture.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray( availableCameraSettings, completionHandler: nil )
    }
    
   
    
    func configSession(){
        
        session.stopRunning()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        
        session.sessionPreset = .photo
        
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput( device: getDevice() )
 
        if( session.canAddOutput( capture ) ){
            session.addOutput( capture )
        }
        
        if ( session.canAddInput( input! ) ){
            session.addInput( input! )
        }
        
        session.commitConfiguration()
        
    }
    
    func startSesssion(){
        session.startRunning()
    }
    
    func stopSession(){
        session.stopRunning()
    }
    
    func getDevice() -> AVCaptureDevice{

        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                for: .video, position: .back) {
            return device
        } else {
            fatalError("Missing expected back camera device.")
        }
    }
    
    func getBestSettings() -> AVCapturePhotoSettings{
        return AVCapturePhotoSettings( /*    rawPixelFormatType: 0 */ )
    }

    
    func createSettings(){
        
        let settings = getBestSettings()
        settings.flashMode = .on
        if #available(iOS 14.1, *) {
            settings.isAutoContentAwareDistortionCorrectionEnabled = false
        } 
        settings.isAutoRedEyeReductionEnabled = false
        settings.isCameraCalibrationDataDeliveryEnabled = false
        settings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = false
        settings.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = false
        
        availableCameraSettings.append( settings )
        let ditto = AVCapturePhotoSettings( from: settings )
        ditto.flashMode = .off
        availableCameraSettings.append( ditto )
    }

    func captureImage()
    {
        for setting in availableCameraSettings{

            let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings( from: setting )
            capture.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self )

        }

    }
    
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
     didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
     error: Error?)
    {
        if error != nil {
            print( error!.localizedDescription )
            prompt.prompt ( Info( error!.localizedDescription, 0 ) )
        } else{
            print( photo.timestamp )
            print ( ( photo.isRawPhoto ? " Raw" : " Not raw" ) + "\n" )
            DispatchQueue.global( qos: .background ).async {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound( 1108 )
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: This is essentially impossible, as pointed out in the answer below - unless you pause the ARSession. I am now using the image from the ARSession instead.

Comment: why do you set isAutoRedEyeReductionEnabled to false?
Does it actually disable the RedEye reduction pre-flash?

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a capture session to my knowledge, as the ARSession is holding on to the camera(s), so you won't be able to capture an image exactly how you want.

However, to get the scene without all the 3d objects, you can get the image the ARSession is currently using like this:
`self.arView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage`
Where `self.arView` is the current ARView.

capturedImage is a CVPixelBuffer, and there's many ways to convert that to a UIImage or whatever else you might want, something like this:

```swift
if let img = self.arView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage {
    let ciimg = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: img)
    let finImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciimg)
}
```

You may have to adjust the image for device orientation too.

---

*Original answer:*

If you want the scene with the 3d objects `view.snapshot(:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/3255319-snapshot

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for the quick answer.
I am aware of this function, however it is my understanding that this will capture what is on the screen ( with the AR scene visible) . I need to capture the underlying scene without any virtual objects in raw and control the flash amongst other things.

Comment: Just adjusted my answer! hopefully that's more what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, I am now using the ArSession to do this. Working well